# Setting MongoDB's write concern in shell / shell script

Tags: mongodb, shell

I'm trying to populate a collection within **MongoDB**'s shell. As I understand, using a relaxed `Write Concern` can speed up the process a lot. I'm talking about [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#write-operations-write-concern) on how `Write Concerns` work but all it talks about is how they work and not how to set them (it says this is set in the driver). And I've seen documents for different drivers and how it is set in them but I can't seem to find how `Write Concerns` are set in **MongoDB**'s shell itself! Does anyone know how to set them from the shell?

**[UPDATE]**

To populate my database I used a `.js` file and gave it to `mongo` command like this:

```
mongo ./test.js
```

And here's the content of `test.js` file:

```
for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    db.kingdom.insert([
        { "counter" : 0, "last_update" : new Date() }
        , { "counter" : 0, "last_update" : new Date() }
        ...
        , { "counter" : 0, "last_update" : new Date() }
    ]);
}
```

The data array goes for 100 objects of the same structure.

Comment: the shell uses safe in that it called getLastError after every "command" (i.e. carriage return).  If you are writing data, say, in a loop then GLE will only be called once at the end.  Provide more details about how you plan to populate collection from the shell - maybe the right thing will already happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can [specify a write concern for each insert/update operation](http://specify.io/mongodb#CRUDDurability):

> db.blogs.insert({title: 'new blog post'}, {writeConcern: {j: true}})

Comment: Sure, you can specify a WriteConcern but even by looking at [mongodb's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/), I couldn't figure out the right syntax. There is only written: 

    { w: <value>, j: <boolean>, wtimeout: <number> }

There is no evidence that this has to be the value of field `writeConcern` as you have figured out (how did you do?). Thanks!